# If everything is God's creation then why do we discriminate between animal and Humans?

Tags: ethics

Albeit Animals cannot speak for themselves but just like Humans their lives must be considered valuable implying eating meat should be as heinous as eating human flesh.

How does Religious texts tackle it? What's their argument to justify meat eating but not cannibalism?

Comment: The question is a non-sequitur. There is no reason why God's having made both humans and animals means that we should not discriminate against animals. The same man might dig a latrine and a well; does that mean we should not distinguish between them?

Comment: @DavidGudeman Yes Sir you got the point.!

Comment: You are aware that HUMANS are ANIMALS correct? The main distinction is what we call intelligence. If we add that GOD designed humans with a body, a Spirit and a touch of the Holy Spirit this further distinguishes the groups. We are not sure if the other animals have spirits. Angels also were created by GOD and their intelligence blows ours away by light years allegedly. Angel's have no souls & no salvation is possible for them while humans can have salvation. These are basic distinctions we all should know regardless anyone's belief in religion.

Comment: This question is a bit obscure. "God" according to which philosophical or. religious tradition? If you mean Judeo-Christian, tradition, state so clearly. Else almost anything can be said on the matter.

Comment: @Logikal I would say the main distinction is degree of agency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animals eat each other all the time, and no immorality is assumed on their part. So humans eating other animals is the most natural thing there is. The big question is: Why should humans not kill each other and indulge in cannibalism?

Ultimately, the answer in religious texts (at least the Bible) is simple but not very satisfying: God said so, and He is the one making the rules.

Taking the Bible as example:

In Genesis 2-3 we only hear of men eating fruits and vegetables. But the very first thing that happens when they are driven from the Garden of Eden is that God makes clothes from animal skin. In Genesis 4 we see animals being herded (and killed for religious sacrifice). No real explanation in between. Then, still in Genesis 4, the first murder and God immediately making clear that murder is not Ok. Again, no real explanation.

You can come up with explanations, sure. Man is said to be special: in the image of God, having dominion over everything on the earth. As such killing man is blasphemy, and killing animals is the natural order of things.

God clearly said in Genesis 1:29 that the food for man and animal is grains and fruits. Yet after the fall, animals are clearly a resource for clothing, and food as well. But what happened in between those two points, is not really explained. Abel performs a sacrifice, which is seen as good, but there is never an explanation why. Did God instruct man to sacrifice? What did he tell them that isn't written in Genesis? We will never know (unless God suddenly decides to tell us).

Comment: So, if we were the ones making the rules instead of God, wouldn't one of the first rules be "don't eat humans"?

Comment: This question is a bit obscure. "God" according to which philosophical or. religious tradition? If it means Judeo-Christian tradition, it should state so clearly and instead be addressed on Christianity foeum. Else almost anything can be said on the matter

Comment: @NikosM. I read in the question "How does Religious texts tackle it?", and since that is pretty broad, and I only really know Christianity, that's what OP gets as answer.

Comment: @ScottRowe Sure. In that case the answer becomes "because we as society decided it was immoral. (Probably because no one wants to be eaten.)". In any case, the question asked how religious texts handle the question.